# Get concrete value of generic parameter during annotation processing

Tags: java, metaprogramming, javac, annotation-processing

I have:

```
class Base<E> {
  E e;
  abstract void f(E other);
}

class Ext extends Base<String> {
  // HERE
}
```

I'd like to generate an implementation of `f(E other)` in `Ext`, but can't figure out how to tell the generator that `E` is `String` in this class. Base classes might be interfaces as well.
I have `JCClassDecl`, so can check `decl.type.extending` and `implementing`, but this manual looking through quickly turns out into a mess and what I currently have is not universally working, so I'd like to skip posting the wrong code and ask the question in its current, general form.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I got it. Spent a day looking for an answer, then, after asking the question, needed about 30 minutes to figure it out.

The answer is: `Types#memberType`:

```
getTypes().memberType(
  classDecl.sym.type,                // this is the extending JCClassDecl
  varDecl.vartype.type.tsym          // this is the parameter JCVarDecl
)
```

Seeing as `javac` API is rather hard to grasp, I hope this will help someone.